# ASP.NET 4.5 model binding customize updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-binding, asp.net-4.5

I am using the ASP.NET forms model binding that was added in .NET 4.5. I see that there are many things about model binding that is supposed to make it easier and reduce how much code you need to write. However, I want to know if there is a way you can update items manually.

I have found the TryUpdateModel method like so:

```
public void UpdateEquipment(int Id)
{
    var equip = EquipCondContext.Equipments.Single(x => x.Id == Id);
    TryUpdateModel(equip);
}
```

but, I would like to have the ability to do this:

```
public void UpdateEquipment(int Id)
{
    var equip = EquipCondContext.Equipments.Single(x => x.Id == Id);
    //equip.Description = A TextBox.Text on that row that I just saved in my list.
    EquipCondContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is there a way I can do a more manual kind of updating like that?

---

Here is an example scenario. Lets say I have a textbox on a row where a user enters a user ID, but on the update I want to actually set their badge number. In my update function, I first want to do a query to get the badge number for the given user ID and then set this property in my entity before saving the context.

Comment: In 2nd example you don't need model binding at all.

Comment: Maybe it would make things clearer if you gave an example of what you are trying to achieve. Why do you want to update manually?

Comment: Your second example will work.   TryUpdateModel will use your model `equip` and a the default value providers (Form, Querystring, etc) and attempt to set values by matching names on your model.

Comment: @Nenad. I know I don't need model binding in the 2nd one. I was just writing a line as an example to setting the properties manually if I wanted to. I have added an example to give better justification/a scenario on why I want this capability.

Comment: @atticae I have added a scenario/example for you.

Comment: Textbox.Text is badge nuber, ok. But still, you don't have any additional properties to bind. Right?

Comment: @Neand, The scenario I gave isn't my exact situation. I am just trying to come up with a case where I want to do more customization to the update than just calling `TryUpdateModel` as I will probably encounter that situation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is hooking into the model binding process and changing values before they are saved. I am not sure if the model binding in Webforms is 1:1 the same as in MVC, but you could try this article:

http://www.markeverard.com/2011/07/18/creating-a-custom-modelbinder-allowing-validation-of-injected-composite-models/

The article is about validation, but you could just as easily change the values there.

Basically what you do is to register a custom ModelBinder for your class which then hooks into the call to bind the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track changes in the Textbox manually you have to listen to the [`Textbox.TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx).

```
<asp:Textbox ... OnTextChanged="MyTextBoxOnTextChanged" />
```

There you can do with the textbox value whatever you want, in your case store it as the according equipment description.